# Asp Net Core on Ubuntu - access is denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04, hosting

After installing library **MailKit** and calling `new SmtpClient().ConnectAsync(_settings.Server, _settings.Port, _settings.SSL);` I get this error:

> Access to the path '/var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls' is denied.

by the way, my project is located on */media/ProjectName*.
i tried perform this: `sudo chmod -R 755 /var` but i got permission error.

here is stacktrace:

> at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)↵   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)↵   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CrlCache.GetCachedCrlPath(X509Certificate2 cert, Boolean mkDir)↵   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CrlCache.DownloadAndAddCrl(X509Certificate2 cert, SafeX509StoreHandle store, TimeSpan& remainingDownloadTime)↵   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CrlCache.AddCrlForCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert, SafeX509StoreHandle store, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan& remainingDownloadTime)↵   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509ChainProcessor.BuildChain(X509Certificate2 leaf, HashSet`1 candidates, HashSet`1 downloaded, HashSet`1 systemTrusted, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan& remainingDownloadTime)↵   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan timeout)↵   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate)↵   at System.Net.Security.CertificateValidation.BuildChainAndVerifyProperties(X509Chain chain, X509Certificate2 remoteCertificate, Boolean checkCertName, String hostName)↵   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake()↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)↵   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)↵   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)↵   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)↵   at MailKit.MailService.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__0()↵   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)↵   at MyProject.Services.MessageService.d__4.MoveNext()↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)↵   at MyProject.Services.MessageService.d__5.MoveNext()

Comment: The call stack indicates that the code is trying to build and access a certificate cache. You can manually create the directory and grant the necessary permissions. Don't modify /var top directory as that's crazy.

Comment: thank you, @LexLi . I should have created this directory before writing this post. It works!

Answer (score 9):

As Lex Li posted create directory /var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls and give rights to www-data group (if this is the group that runs your service)

sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls

Comment: First, you need to recursively create the directory: mkdir -p /var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls

Answer (score 2):

I was referring this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction). In the kestrel-hellomvc.service file replaced User=www-data with User=my-root-username and it worked.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: does this mean the kestrel anonymous web server is running as root?